# Java select specific case and output only that case when the switch is in a loop using counter

Tags: java, loops, methods, switch-statement

I'm relatively new to coding and I've encountered a problem with switches, a loop and choosing which case to output and not output every case before that case as well.

I'm aware this problem is because of the counter, because the counter only gets to my case by counting upwards and outputting every case in the way to get the the one I want, only stopping there. But that's not even it, in **this program it outputs all the case regardless of what I input!** I have very little idea of what to do.

I tried using break loops, but the outcome was pretty expected. It only outputs the first case.

The point of this program is to write to a file called "foo.txt" and after a user inputs a specific letter from "COMPUTERS", a single line from the text in "foo.txt" is outputted. There are 9 letters in "COMPUTERS" and 9 sentences in "foo.txt". No hard coding allowed.

*QUESTION:* **How can I, in a switch inside a loop, select a specific case and only output that case?**

*ANY* help is highly appeciated.

```
// The "Lab_raminAmiri" class.
import java.io.*;
public class Lab_raminAmiri
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        sendLines ();
        userInputChar ();
        readLines ();
    } // main method


    public static void sendLines ()
    {
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("foo.txt");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (fw);

            pw.println ("\nCome to the lab on time.");
            pw.println ("Operate your computer properly.");
            pw.println ("Make sure to listen attentively.");
            pw.println ("Print only what is required.");
            pw.println ("Use the Net with respect.");
            pw.println ("Touch the keyboard gently.");
            pw.println ("Eat or drink outside the lab.");
            pw.println ("Remember to finish your assignment.");
            pw.println ("Shutdown the computer at the end of class.");

            pw.close ();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
    } //sendLines method


    public static void userInputChar ()
    {
        char input;

        System.out.println ("Enter a letter from the word COMPUTERS");
        input = In.getChar ();
    }


    public static void readLines ()
    {

        FileReader fr;
        int counter = -1;
        String line = null;


        try
        {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("foo.txt"));

            System.out.print ("\nLine printed: ");


            loop:
            while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null)
            {

                counter++;

                switch (counter)
                {

                    case 1:
                    case 'c':
                        System.out.println ("1: " + line);
                        break loop;

                    case 2:
                    case 'o':
                        System.out.println ("2: " + line);
                        break loop;

                    case 3:
                    case 'm':
                        System.out.println ("3: " + line);
                        break loop;

                    case 4:
                    case 'p':
                        System.out.println ("4: " + line);
                        break loop;

                    case 5:
                    case 'u':
                        System.out.println ("5: " + line);
                        break loop;

                    case 6:
                    case 't':
                        System.out.println ("6: " + line);
                        break loop;

                    case 7:
                    case 'e':
                        System.out.println ("7: " + line);
                        break loop;

                    case 8:
                    case 'r':
                        System.out.println ("8: " + line);
                        break loop;

                    case 9:
                    case 's':
                        System.out.println ("9: " + line);
                        break loop;
                }
            }

            br.close ();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
    } //readLines method
} // Lab_raminAmiri class
```

Comment: for a start never silently swallow your exceptions - print them out

Comment: secondly what is this `case 1:     case 'c':` what do you think it does?

Comment: @ScaryWombat the case 1: case 'c' is so that I can also take the input 'c' to print the same thing as getting the input '1', because the user has to input a letter for them to get a sentence and not a number. This was the only way I knew of doing this

Comment: @ScaryWombat What do you mean by not swallowing my exceptions and printing them?

Comment: you are switching on `counter` so `case 1:` means when the value of `count == 1` *do this* It does not make sense to have `case c`, counter can only be one value at a time.  In code like `catch (IOException e)
        {
        }` you should print out the exception - it will tell you something **very** important

Comment: @ScaryWombat Then how would I print case 1 using the input "c"? Also, what's the best way to print the exception? What will it tell me?

Comment: *Then how would I print case 1 using the input "c"?* this does not make sense.  To print an exception try `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Getting the input '1' would print case 1, correct? I want another input to print case 1 as well, that input being 'c'. **edit:** going to sleep for today. Gonna come back tomorrow and further discuss this because I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Using break like a GOTO is very odd in Java, break; by itself is suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading input in different method you can take input in "readLines" method itself.

Try the below code:

```
public static void readLines()
{
        char input;
        System.out.println ("Enter a letter from the word COMPUTERS");
        input = In.getChar ();
        switch (input)
        {
            case 'C':
            String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("foo.txt")).get(1);

            case 'O':
            String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("foo.txt")).get(2);

            System.out.println (line);
            // Like wise for other characters.
        }

}
```

Comment: I can an error when I try to use "Paths.get" is there something I'm missing?

Comment: No field name "Paths" was found

Comment: Please check with your Java version, it should be 1.7 or higher versions.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not make sense as you are reading the value, but not returning it

```
public static void userInputChar ()
{
    char input;

    System.out.println ("Enter a letter from the word COMPUTERS");
    input = In.getChar ();
}
```

I am guessing that you want to use this value in your `switch` statment, so some thing needs to be returned like:

```
public static char userInputChar ()
{
    char input;

    System.out.println ("Enter a letter from the word COMPUTERS");
    input = In.getChar ();
    return  input;
}
```

now that you have returned this value, keep it like:

```
char input = userInputChar ();
```

now pass it to your `switch` method

```
readLines (input);
```

change your method declaration

```
public static void readLines (char input)
```

now you can use it

```
  while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null)
  {

       if (line.charAt(0) == input) {
       {
          System.out.println (line);
          break;
       }
  }
  // close files etc
```

**edit**

To make the above safer do,

```
       if (line.length() > 0 && line.charAt(0) == input) {
       {
          System.out.println (line);
          break;
       }
```

Comment: It says "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0" when I try to run it and type input "C". I have to make char input = 0; in the main method so is that the problem? otherwise it gives error

Comment: here is the re-made version with the error I stated above: https://pastebin.com/JfeQ28M7

Comment: a couple of problems with your code a) in `main` you did not keep the return value of `userInputChar` as in `char input = userInputChar ();`  b) in `readLines` you are only re-reading the `line` if the first char matches your input.  You want to do it in all **other** case - see my code.  **Also** in my code (and your original) code, it is better to check that the length of `line` is greater than 0 before doing `line.charAt(0)` - see my edit

Answer (score 0):

This program writes lines to file. Then it asks user to enter a letter from word computers or enter q to exit. When user types letter like s it reads from file line that starts with S. If user types q the program stops. If user types unknown letter like w it prints null. Here is code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.dao;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab_raminAmiri {
    private static char input;
    private static String fileName = "foo.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        sendLines();

        Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
        RandomAccessFile fileReader = new RandomAccessFile(new File(fileName), "r");
        System.out.println("Enter a letter from the word computers or q to exit");
        String next = null;
        while ((next = In.next()) != null && next.length() > 0) {
            input = next.charAt(0);
            if (!String.valueOf(input).equals("q")) {
                String line = readLineStartingWith(input, fileReader);
                System.out.println(input + ": " + line);
                // make file-pointer point to begin of file
                fileReader.seek(0);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        In.close();
        fileReader.close();
    } // main method

    public static void sendLines() throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        pw.println("Come to the lab on time.");
        pw.println("Operate your computer properly.");
        pw.println("Make sure to listen attentively.");
        pw.println("Print only what is required.");
        pw.println("Use the Net with respect.");
        pw.println("Touch the keyboard gently.");
        pw.println("Eat or drink outside the lab.");
        pw.println("Remember to finish your assignment.");
        pw.println("Shutdown the computer at the end of class.");

        pw.close();
    } // sendLines method

    private static String readLineStartingWith(char firstLatter, RandomAccessFile fileReader) throws IOException {
        String line;
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null && line.length() > 0) {
            String upperCase = String.valueOf(firstLatter).toUpperCase();
            if (line.startsWith(upperCase))
                return line;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```